# C++ using "-" operand together with list.back()

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

I want to go trough a list in a for-loop and do something like this:

```
list<my_object> my_list;

for(int x = 0; x < my_list.size(); x++){

   my_object tempObject = (my_list.back() - x);

   //more actions...

}
```

But even though http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/back/ shows and example where you use the "-" operator together with the "back()" function, Visual C++ tells me "no operator "-" matches these operands"...

I started c++ a couple of days ago and I have no idea where to go from here.. Is it even possible to go trough the list this way?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Comment: The example you've linked to works because that `list` contains `int`s, and `int` supports subtraction.  Your list contains `my_object`s, so unless `my_object` supports "subtraction", then this won't compile.

Comment: Is the `back() - x` part supposed to iterate through the list backwards? What it actually does is subtract `x` from the value at the back of the list, so it's not really clear what you actually want the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to iterate through a list is to use iterators:

```
list<my_object> my_list;

for (list<my_object>::iterator i(my_list.begin()), end(my_list.end()); i!=end; ++i) {
   my_object tempObject = *i;

   //more actions...

}
```

Using iterators with C++11:

```
for (auto i = begin(my_list), end = end(my_list); i!=end(); ++i) {
   my_object tempObject = *i;

   //more actions...

}
```

You can use a C++11 range based for loop:

```
for (my_object tempObject : my_list) {

   //more actions...

}
```

Or if there happens to be an STL style algorithm template that already does your 'more actions':

```
more_actions(begin(my_list),end(my_list));
```

Comment: You're using mutable iterators, but then create a copy of *i?

Comment: The original code makes a copy. I wouldn't recommend it, but that's beyond the scope of the question. Nor do I see that as a reason to use const iterators.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you link to the element inside the list is an `int` which is why it works there. What you are trying to do is subtract an integer from an instance of `my_object`. There is no built in function to do this operation but if there is a function `operator-(my_object &lhs, int rhs)` then it could be possible.